# Xdebug 3.2 showing double results in PhpStorm (arrays, objects, etc.)

Tags: php, debugging, phpstorm, xdebug

**EDIT:** I am running PhpStorm version 2022.3.2 Build #PS-223.8617.59, built on January 30, 2023

Bug Report on YouTrack here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-71780/I-am-seeing-double-output-with-Xdebug-3-in-PhpStorm-2022.3.2

Here is some sample code that produces the same issue of doubling up on my build and version number.

```php
<?php

$names = ['John', 'Jane', 'Joe'];

foreach ($names as $name) {
    if (substr($name, 0, 1) == 'J') {
        echo $name . ' starts with J </br>';
    }
}

?>
```

[image: Issue Persists]

---

**Original Question**

I have googled quite a bit trying to figure this out, but have not come across anything yet that I can see addresses this. I have also checked on this site and see nothing that mentions this issue that I can find.

I just setup Xdebug 3 with PhpStorm and I am seeing everything doubled up when it shows the contents of anything. Image below to show what I mean.

[image: Xdebug Doubles Up]

I only have one xdebug.dll setup in my PHP folder and have PhpStorm pointed to the active *php.ini* file.

Here is my php.ini settings for Xdebug:

```ini
zend_extension="C:\xampp\php\php_xdebug-3.2.0-8.2-vs16-x86_64.dll"
xdebug.mode=debug
xdebug.client_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.client_port="9003"
```

I'm running PHP 8.2 with Thread Safety and have made sure to download the Xdebug version the matches this.

Here is an image of the `phpinfo()` showing my Xdebug is installed.
[image: Xdebug1]
[image]

It debugs fine, and steps through like it should, just a really annoying visual thing, especially on longer arrays or objects, to see it doubled up like this.

I am using the Chrome extension that lets me trigger debugging, profiling, and tracing to send over the connection to PhpStorm. I have mapped everything as expected and have no issues hitting my breakpoints, which leads me to believe everything is setup correctly. So not sure why it is doing this.

Has anyone encountered anything like this?

Comment: This has to be an IDE (PhpStorm) issue and not Xdebug (as it's IDE that decides what to write and where). What's you PhpStorm version?

Comment: I have failed to find any tickets about inline debugger displaying the same variable twice. The only ticket I was able to find is from 2015 when this functionality was introduced (https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-26429)... **Question:** 1) Can you make another project and reproduce it there? 2) What about reproducing in in the same project in some simple (standalone) file that does not use your framework/complex logic. It could be specific to your setup or a code base. Need some reproducible code sample that can be easily tested on another machine.

Comment: I have edited the original post to include the version and build number of PhpStorm as well as a small sample snippet that can be used to test off of. As you can see from the screenshot, it doubles up as well as doubling up the {} and [] notation. Let me know if you need anything additional for testing. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, I can reproduce the issue with your code on PhpStorm 2022.3.2 using a CLI debug session with PHP 8.0.28 x64 nts build + Xdebug v3.2 (have not tried any other ones).

Comment: From what I see you have made a ticket already: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-71780/I-am-seeing-double-output-with-Xdebug-3-in-PhpStorm-2022.3.2

Comment: The issue is not present with **Xdebug 3.1.6** on the same PHP

Comment: Yeah after googling some more, I decided a ticket was warranted. I will download and setup the Xdebug 3.1.6 dll and give that a try, thank you so much. I will let you know how it goes!

Comment: Ok so it works as expected once I downgraded my PHP install and used the Xdebug 3.1.6 version. 3.1.6 didn't have a PHP 8.2 install, so had to downgrade, but not a huge issue for my works codebase. Guess I will just need to wait for a fix to come through from JetBrains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so the bug has been reported and has been marked fixed on YouTrack here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-71780/I-am-seeing-double-output-with-Xdebug-3-in-PhpStorm-2022.3.2

They have not released the fix yet to my knowledge, but I assume that it will be in the next release or patch fix.